# Relative Source Binding Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

My problem is with the viewcell, the OnDelete command is not found due to it being of the IssueModel class, I've attempted to change the binding-context of the Listview, but that doesn't change anything except the above binding.

Is there any way to change the binding context of the viewcell so I don't have to put the command into to IssueModel?

```
freshMvvm:FreshBaseContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:ASFT.Converters;assembly=ASFT"
             xmlns:freshMvvm="clr-namespace:FreshMvvm;assembly=FreshMvvm"
             xmlns:helperMethods="clr-namespace:ASFT.HelperMethods;assembly=ASFT"
             x:Class="ASFT.Pages.IssueListPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:SelectedItemEventArgsToSelectedItemConverter x:Key="SelectedItemConverter" />
            <converters:DateTextConverter x:Key="DateToTextConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Issues}" SeparatorColor="#444444" RowHeight="90" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy}" RefreshCommand="{Binding PullRefreshCommand}" >
        <ListView.Behaviors>
        <helperMethods:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemSelected" 
                                          Command="{Binding OnSelectedIssueCommand}" 
                                          Converter="{StaticResource SelectedItemConverter}" />
        </ListView.Behaviors>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell >
                    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <MenuItem  Command="{Binding OnDelete}"  Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" />
                    </ViewCell.ContextActions>

                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding SeverityImagePath}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="70"/>
                            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="2" Source="{Binding StatusImagePath}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="60"/>

                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" YAlign="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" Font="Bold, Medium"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Created, Converter={StaticResource DateToTextConverter}}" YAlign="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" Font="Medium"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" YAlign="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" Font="Small"/>
                        </Grid>

                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</freshMvvm:FreshBaseContentPage>
```

Edit:

I've attempted one of the answers but that didn't work. This just gets an error message: expected type is object, but type is IssueListPageModel

```
     xmlns:pageModels="clr-namespace:ASFT.PageModels;assembly=ASFT"



 <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.OnDelete, Source={pageModels:IssueListPageModel}}" Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" />
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add a `x:Name` attribute to your `freshMvvm:FreshBaseContentPage`, like i.e.: `x:Name="MyAwesomePage"`.

Now change your `ViewCell` binding like this:

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.OnDelete, Source={x:Reference Name=MyAwesomePage}}" Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" />
```

Now the binding source is set to the page by using its name. And the path is set to the property `BindingContext.OnDelete`. So, in your backing view model for this page there should be a `OnDelete` property.

To clarify the separate components like you've asked in the comments.

The `Path=` is omitted with a regular binding. When not explicitly mentioned, `{Binding MyProperty}` means the same as '{Binding Path=MyProperty}'. `Path` means the path to the value that needs to be bound from the `BindingContext`, so effectively the property that you are binding to.

The `Source` is used to specify what is the source of the `Path`. Which is in itself another binding. In our case to a reference which is known by the name we just gave the page. This way, the binding of the `ViewCell` knows to start at the `Source` and then search for the `Path` to retrieve its value. I hope this makes it a bit clear.

You can reference anything here if you want to, as long as you have access to the instance of the class here. I would, however, recommend to keep it to the `BindingContext` which is effectively the view model (note: `BindingContext` is the actual property of your page that contains the view model). Else you will lose overview very quickly.

Comment: Hi Gerald! I've seen this before on the xamarin website but they don't explain what the individual Components do. What does Binding Path, Source do? I just want to learn from this for the future.

Comment: And how do I use this to do it with an ViewModel/PageModel? I can't do an x:reference on a normal c# class?

Comment: Updated answer for you!

Comment: Still not sure how to do it with my own example in my own edit, as the pagemodel could not be found and you can't x:name a regular class?

Comment: How would you do it with something that is not a page?