# How can I open a hyperlink from an Xamarin xaml forms app?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Please see the XAML code below:

```
<ListView x:Name="persons" ItemsSource="{Binding Person}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="45" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label  FontSize="10" Grid.Column="3" TextColor="Blue" Text="Go to site">
                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding URL}"/>
                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Label>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I have added the following code to my view model:

```
public ICommand ClickCommand => new Command<string>(async (url) =>
{
    Device.OpenUri(new Uri(url));
});
```

The code in the view model is not called when I click on the hyperlink.  How can I open a hyperlink from an Xamarin xaml forms app? I am happy to use a button; label or whatever.

I have spent the last two hours Googling this and I have go nowhere and hence the reason for the question.

Comment: Is `ClickCommand` a property of the item in the `Person` collection? That is, the same object that has the `URL` property? I think your problem is just how to bind to the command property. Is `ClickCommand` a property of the same viewmodel that owns the `Person` property?

Comment: @Ed Plunkett, no; ClickCommand is not a property of the Person class.

Comment: So `Person` (the property bound to ItemsSource) is a collection of a class named `Person`? Well, anyway, that's your problem: The source of that binding is, by default, the `Person` being displayed by the DataTemplate. IIRC Xamarin calls that the `BindingContext`. Is `URL` a property of `Person`? What you need to do is get your command binding to look at the correct binding context to find `ClickCommand`. One easy way to do that is simply make `ClickCommand` a property of `Person`.

Comment: [This solution would work also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49507128/424129): Yours would be `Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ClickCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=persons}}"`, where `persons` is the name of the ListView. This assumes that `ClickCommand` is a property of the same parent viewmodel as the `Person` collection is.